# Bias common mode and Impendence in relation to ASD1299

Tags: bias, common-mode, ads, drift

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me understand the Bias common mode and Impendence in relation to ADS1299.

If someone has a ADS1299 for dummies that would be great

Thanks